# What's the scope in object literal definitions.

Tags: javascript, scope

I am learning javascript and my current understanding is the main way javascript uses for scoping is the function scope, and there are no block scopes in general.

So I came up with this:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: function myfunc() {
    console.log("123");
  }
};

myfunc();
```

I thought because javascript doesn't have block scoping, the definition of `myfunc()` will be visible in global scope. But it actually did not. Can someone help to explain this?

Comment: You know that you can access it via `obj.foo()`, right?

Comment: You can't just execute myFunc(), rather obj.foo()

Comment: It's a function expression. It never becomes available in any scope.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but my question is does literal object definitions create a block scope

Comment: @dangor I know I can't, cause I tried it, but is there any place documents this? does the object creation define a block scope?

Comment: Also `var foo = function myfunc() {}; myfunc();` does not work, because of the expression.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you:) I never thought of that.

Comment: @Chris Object scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three points where your understanding is flawed:

- JavaScript *does* have block scopes since ES6.
- Object literals are no blocks, they do not introduce any scopes.
- Your function is not becoming a global because it is not a declaration (which is syntactically invalid inside an object), but a function expression that just creates a named function object which then is assigned to the `foo` property of the newly created object. See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) for details.

Comment: @shengy: The downvote means "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".